# Syntax error in lambda

Tags: haskell, lambda

I don't see the error, unless I'm missing something.

```
loadFiles :: FilePath -> IO [B.ByteString]
loadFiles dir = do
        filePaths <- (getDirectoryContents dir)
        mapM (\x loadFile (dir ++ x)) filePaths
```

I get the error `main.hs:33:37: Parse error in pattern: dir ++ x`

Comment: (\x -> loadFile (dir ++ x))

Answer (score 8):

You are missing the arrow:

```
    (\x -> loadFile (dir ++ x))
```